# Returning an Array results within a method

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

**Problem solved.**

I have two methods in my class.

```
private void retrieveDetails(){
List<String> details = File.getCredentials();
username = details.get(0);
pw = details.get(1);
}

private void checkCredentials() throws IOException {
        retrieveDetails();
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter USERNAME: ");
        String usersName = scan.next();

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter PASSWORD: ");
        String usersPW = scan.next();

        System.out.println("\nEntered details: " + usersName + ", " + usersPW);
        System.out.println("\nSystems details: " + userName + ", " + pw);

        if (usersName.equals(username) && usersPW.equals(pw)) {
            doWork();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect credentials");
        }
    }
```

I thought I came up with a solution by moving the following up to where my strings are initialized.

```
List<String> creds = File.getCredentials();
```

I created a `System.out` statement to check if the details coming from `retrieveDetails()` match those entered by the users. They do match - but when the system goes to the else clause instead of executing `doWork();`

Comment: What is `plainPassword` and `pw`? Are they same or different?

Comment: What is the implementation of `File.getCredentials()`? Check that the strings you are returning from it are trimmed.

Comment: This is because `(userName != username) || (plainPassword != pw)`

Comment: @ShivaKumar - My mistake. plainPassword should be pw.

Comment: @AdamHinx what about `userName` ?

Comment: So you have 3 variables: usersName, username and userName? No wonder you don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what is printed is the same then try trimming before comparing. E.g.:

`if (usersName.trim().equals(username.trim()) && usersPW.trim().equals(pw.trim())) {`

Comment: Thanks @Cratylus. This had worked. Am i correct in thinking the .trim() removes spaces from variables?

Comment: @AdamHinx:`trim` returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.If it worked then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

When i have similar problem i do this simple trick:

Print the size of the strings you are comparing because sometimes you have characters like \n or \r which are not visible when you print the string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like you have a typo in sysout statement below.

```
System.out.println("\nEntered details: " + usersName + ", " + usersPW);
System.out.println("\nSystems details: " + userName + ", " + pw); //Should be username
```

Secondly, you might wanna trim the strings for better string comparison. 
Sometimes strings read from file or console can contain unwanted and hard-to-catch empty strings like spaces and tabs. These can be removed by calling .trim() method on strings.

Thus, try using the following code instead:

```
if (usersName.trim().equals(username.trim()) && usersPW.trim().equals(pw.trim())) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
usersName.equals(username) && usersPW.equals(pw).
```

I have faced these problem also, These kind of equality always tricky, Try to **trim** the **strings** that you are going to compare, as well as if you can  compare these strings based on their length.

```
if (usersName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(username.trim()) && usersPW.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(pw.trim()))
```

**or**
`if (usersName.trim().length()==username.trim().length && usersPW.trim().length()==pw.trim().length))`